# circletype with scroll hide show function not working

Tags: jquery

Ok, so one of my website have a logo which circle when scrolling. We are using this js library: https://circletype.labwire.ca/
& this is the code we are using:

Html:

```
<div class="circular-text">
<div class="text">
</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .text");
const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(65);
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  text.style.transform = `rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`;
});
```

What I need is now to show this logo after 500px of scrolling, so I add this js to it:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop()>500)
     {
        jQuery('.circular-text').show();
     }
    else
     {
      jQuery('.circular-text').hide();
     }
 });
```

but it's not working, I dont know js very well. How to solve this problem? Also rather than adding two block of js codes, can it be done in the first block?

Comment: It has to be `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: Sorry it already has the parenthesis, If forgot to add them here.

Comment: To answer your question: Can it be done in first block? Sure but in general it's not a good idea to mix jquery and javascript. Pick one and code with that.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Can you tell me how do I add the hide show method in first block of code?